# post build action with parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 2 parameterized pipeline A and B.
project A execute project B as a post build action.
Im using "Predefine parameters" to pass parameters to project B, but seems project B using default values and not the provided one.
the pass parameter is project A parameter.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins can get weird around parameters. If you are using a declarative pipeline, then define the parameters within the code instead of using the option on the Jenkins page:

```
build([
    job       : 'B',
    wait      : false,
    parameters: [
            string(name: 'process_id', value: "${id}")
    ]
])
```

And in pipeline B:

```
parameters {
    string(defaultValue: null, description: 'parameter', name: 'process_id')
}
```

If using freestyle jobs, the way you have defined the parameter is correct. If Jenkins is not using the correct parameter and instead is using some cached value, then try these steps:

1. Clone your downstream job
2. Rename you downstream job to something else
3. Rename the cloned downstream job to the correct name that should be used
4. Run the downstream job once

If the problem is that Jenkins caches the parameters used, this should fix it.